# find element in array and the number of appearances

Tags: c++, search

I need help finding the number of appearances of an element in a sorted list in ascending order.

I had the following code set up, but I'm getting an error at the end of "expected parameter declarator" in my last line of code.  Also it's saying I have no previous prototype of function binarySearch.  What does this even mean?  I looked it up and I declared int binarySearch in the beginning but I had no luck.  I really do not know why this code is not running and I have spent the past two hours debugging.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;  


//sort then search


int binarySearch(int arr[], int value, int left, int right) {
    while (left <= right) {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;

        if (arr[middle] == value)
            return middle;
        else if (arr[middle] > value)
            right = middle - 1;
        else
            left = middle + 1;
    }

    return -1;

}

int main()  
{  
    int a[] = {12,3,4,4,4,5,6,7};

    int num;  

    num = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)  
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";  
    cout<<endl;

    int value;

    cout<<"Enter a value you want to find in the array."<<endl;
    cin>>value;

    cout<<"The element is at "<<int binarySearch(int a[], value, 0, int num);
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework that requires it, you don't need (or want) to write your own binary search. `std::equal_range` will give you exactly what you seem to need.

Comment: A prototype for your function would be the line `int binarySearch(int[], int, int, int);` These are what you typically find within a class body. One flavour of warning warns when you don't have one before defining a global function.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you call a function.  You can't just copy the function definition line and replace one or two arguments.  Replace that line with:

```
cout<<"The element is at "<<binarySearch(a, value, 0, num);
```

Note: This won't address any problems in the algorithm itself, just the problem calling it.